# Kubectl documentation without starting Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, documentation

I have installed a K8S cluster on laptop using Kubeadm and VirtualBox. It seems a bit odd that the cluster has to be up and running to see the documentation as shown below.

```
praveensripati@praveen-ubuntu:~$ kubectl explain pods
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.0.31:6443: connect: no route to host
```

Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See "[kubectl explain — #HeptioProTip](https://blog.heptio.com/kubectl-explain-heptioprotip-ee883992a243)"

> Behind the scenes, **`kubectl` just made an API request to my Kubernetes cluster**, grabbed the current Swagger documentation of the API version running in the cluster, and output the documentation and object types.

Try `kubectl help` as an offline alternative, but that won't be as complete (limite to kubectl itself).

Answer (score 2):

So the rather sobering news is that AFAIK there's not out-of-the box way how to do it, though you could totally write a `kubectl` plugin (it has become rather trivial now in 1.12). But for now, the best I can offer is the following:

```
# figure out which endpoint kubectl uses to retrieve docs:
$ kubectl -v9 explain pods

# from above I learn that in my case it's apparently
# https://192.168.64.11:8443/openapi/v2 so let's curl that:
$ curl -k https://192.168.64.11:8443/openapi/v2 > resources-docs.json
```

From here you can, for example, [use jq](http://andrew.gibiansky.com/blog/command-line/jq-primer/) to query for the descriptions. It's not as nice as a proper explain, but kinda is a good enough workaround until someone writes an docs offline query kubectl plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The 'explain' documentation lives in the [`kube-apiserver`](https://github.com/kubernetes/apiserver) and its resource definitions. Hence the need to connect to it through `kubectl explain` to get any docs.  This is different from the standard very basic cli help from `kubectl` where it's in the [`kubectl`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl) Golang code.

So no workaround really other than setting up a dummy Kubernetes cluster and have kubectl point to it. Please note that [CRDs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/) help might not be available since they live in the deployed CRDs themselves.